# How dangerous are phishing links really?

Tags: phishing

1. Some phishing links contain random digits / codes (e.g: `https://refno1234.example.com`). For such links, is there an increased risk by clicking on them because the unique code could be matched to your email / mobile number and therefore verify it exists?
2. Is it possible, by clicking on a phishing link, to run malicious scripts in the background to steal your personal data/files?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there can be unique identifiers in links that will pair you with that "campaign" and you will be hit again with a more sophisticated attack, now that you are a known "clicker".

Yes, scripts on the webpage you click can steal your credentials, launch malware, encrypt files, etc. [I did a video](https://youtu.be/npmHc-NNvGI) on how I investigated a sophisticated version of this and what exactly it did.

Comment: Does browser sandboxing not avoid this though. It wasn't clear from the video if the attempts to alter files were successful

Comment: Browser sandboxing can help, yes.